# How do I build the 32-bit pypy JIT in 64-bit Linux?

Tags: python, pypy

Pypy's JIT will compile on 64-bit Linux ever since it grew 64-bit support, but what if I wanted to compile a 32-bit version? How should I cross-compile a 32-bit JITting pypy on that machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try compiling it in a chroot.

Comment: It compiles in a chroot. It was much easier to get going than I thought with debootstrap, schroot etc.

Comment: It's worth noting that PyPy has since grown JIT support for 64bit architectures (besides becoming much faster).